# Missing Number Question

Tags: number-sequence

Source : [Briddles.com](http://briddles.com?source=stack&external=1)

Find the missing number
[image]

Comment: You have posted three questions on Puzzling, all in the last week or so. They are all taken from other sites. **1**. Could you please disclose whether you have any sort of connection with gpuzzles.com and briddles.com, the sites in question? **2**. Could you please indicate whether you have permission from the owners of those sites to post their puzzles here?

Comment: **3**. Regardless of the answers to those questions, this really isn't how PSE is intended to be used. If you are only interested in posting here puzzles that are already available elsewhere on the internet, *please stop*. (Voting on those puzzles suggests that the PSE community doesn't consider them particularly good ones in any case.)

Comment: **4**. If you are posting content from elsewhere, you should attribute it *fully*, including (when it's from online) a link to the actual puzzle and not just to the front page of the site you took it from. EXCEPT that if you're reposting something of yours (which you should do sparingly if at all) you should (a) disclose that and (b) *not* link to it at all.

Comment: **5**. In any case, if you are posting *only* or *primarily* content from elsewhere -- whether yours or someone else's, whether to advertise another site or just because you saw something and liked it -- that is really not contributing much value to PSE and we would prefer you not to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy. The answer is

> 6

Because

> Opposite pairs of numbers on the circle add up to 21:
>  13 + 8 = 21
>  10 + 11 = 21
>  4 + 17 = 21
>  15 + **6** = 21
>
>
>  [image]

Comment: Well dang, I got cocky and decided to make an image for this puzzle's answer. Should have realized I was buying others time. Nice job, +1